# convert command of ImageMagick-6 does not run via Run Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, imagemagick

Thank you for having a look.
Here is my simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running!" > /home/../batch/apache_status_label.txt;

convert \label:@/home/../batch/apache_status_label.txt   apache_status_label.gif;
```

The convert statement does not run if I use "Run Bash". However if I execute the file directly using "Run" or by calling it in a Terminal window both statements run fine and the `convert` command (from ImageMagick-6 included with Ubuntu 18.04) executes and generates the image.

I need to use "Run Bash" as I require to call the script from the FireFox web browser. I am completely stumped. Perhaps it is path related to convert but I don't know how to point it to the required file location as I am new to the linux OS environment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this.

When I ran the executable (.sh) file using "Run" it created the image in the same directory as the executable called.

However, when I called the executable using Run Bash or Open with bash in  Firefox (web browser, see image) the image was created but in the user's home directory.
[Firefox - open with bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc8t7.png)

The solution is use a fully qualified path for the image file with the convert command. See the script below. Thank you.

#!/bin/bash

echo "Running!" > /home/../apache_status_label.txt;
convert \label:@/home/../apache_status_label.txt   /home/../apache_status_label.gif;